# Apache kylin cube fails "no counters for job"

Tags: hadoop, hive, kylin

using kylin 1.5.4, when i build the cube it fails at step 3 , log says "no counter for job". It's not fetching cardinality of hive table as well. When i create a model or cube it throws failed to take action error, but when i close the json page, they are created. It isn't fetching the date partition column, throwing column not found in logs.

Any help or insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late to this, but I also had this issue on my current project where I got the "no counters for job" error. The problem was that we were using ORC tables in Hive. We just moved the data from the ORC tables into new TEXTFILE tables and set everything up in the Kylin cube with the new tables and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

When Kylin reports "no counter for job", usually it was because that MR job is failed or the Hadoop history server wasn't started. If the MR got error, you need look into the Hadoop Job logs to see what's the root cause; Could you double check and paste the error trace? also please check whether it matches with [KYLIN-2026](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KYLIN-2026) or [KYLIN-2032](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KYLIN-2032) , which will be fixed in 1.5.4.1